# Error 0x800a01b6 - Object doesn't support property or method 'attachEvent'

Tags: javascript

I'm new in this field and i don't know why it's wrong:

```
if (this.trigger.addEventListener) {
            this.trigger.addEventListener(this.eventtype, function (ev) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                if (self.isMenuOpen) {
                    self._closeMenu();
                    document.removeEventListener(self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn);
                }
                else {
                    self._openMenu();
                    document.addEventListener(self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn);
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.trigger.attachEvent('on' + this.eventtype, function (ev) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                ev.preventDefault();
                if (self.isMenuOpen) {
                    self._closeMenu();
                    document.detachEvent('on' + self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn);
                }
                else {
                    self._openMenu();
                    document.attachEvent('on' + self.eventtype, self.bodyClickFn);
                }
            });
```

the addeventlistener works fine in ie edge, chrome, FF but I need this working in ie7 and i don't find a similar example on my friend google.

Comment: What is `this.trigger`?

Comment: it's an object that open a menu

Comment: "an object" is not specific enough. Everything is "an object" (except primitives)

Comment: sorry. it's a button.

Comment: And are you sure about that? If you do `alert(this.trigger.nodeName)`, do you get `BUTTON`?

Comment: *"no. i'm get undefined."*: Then `this.trigger` is not a DOM element and you can't call `attachEvent` on it. It's as simple as that. Not much we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the access to the element:

```
if (msieversion() <= 7) {
            this.trigger = document.getElementById('t123');
            this.menu = document.getElementById('t456');

        } else {
            this.trigger = this.el.querySelector('a.gn-icon-menu');
            this.menu = this.el.querySelector('nav.gn-menu-wrapper');
        }
```

and the methods `ev.stopPropagation();` and ev.preventDefault(); don't are supported by ie7. the right way:

```
(ev.stopPropagation) ? ev.stopPropagation() : ev.cancelBubble=true ;
(ev.preventDefault) ? ev.preventDefault() : ev.returnValue = false;
```

thanks everyone.